# Remove duplicate value in different categories in same table SQL but keep the first category value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

Let's say I have a table with id and category like the table below

```
 D_id | D_category
-----------------
   1  |   A
   2  |   A
   3  |   A

   1  |   B
   2  |   B
   4  |   B
   5  |   B

   1  |   C
   2  |   C
   4  |   C
   5  |   C
   6  |   C
```

Hence the rules are like this

- values in category A should not be appear in category B and category C
- values in category B should not be appear in category C

The end result should be like this

```
 D_id | D_category
-----------------
   1  |   A
   2  |   A
   3  |   A

   4  |   B
   5  |   B

   6  |   C
```

I will provide a solution that works but its not an ideal solution can anyone help me to provide a better solution in case there are more categories meaning that if there are more category then it should follow the rules the values in previous categories should not appear in any other categories

```
DECLARE @A TABLE(
    D_id INT NOT NULL,
    D_category VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @A(D_id,D_category)
VALUES (1, 'A'),
(2, 'A'),
(3, 'A'),
(1, 'B'),
(2, 'B'),
(4, 'B'),
(5, 'B'),
(1, 'C'),
(2, 'C'),
(4, 'C'),
(5, 'C'),
(6, 'C')

DELETE t
FROM @A t
WHERE t.D_category = 'B' AND  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @A t2 WHERE t2.D_category = 'A' and t.D_id = t2.D_id)

DELETE t
FROM @A t
WHERE t.D_category = 'C' AND  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @A t2 WHERE t2.D_category = 'B' and t.D_id = t2.D_id)

DELETE t
FROM @A t
WHERE t.D_category = 'C' AND  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @A t2 WHERE t2.D_category = 'A' and t.D_id = t2.D_id)

select * from @A
```

Comment: Why did you delete this question earlier and then re-ask under another account? I had been literally about to answer. And having multiple accounts is against the Terms and Conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Just check that the specified record doesn't exist earlier in the sequence.

```
select *
from @A A1
where not exists (
  select 1
  from @A A2
  where A2.D_id = A1.D_id
  and A2.D_category < A1.D_category
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete using the join syntax:

```
delete a
from my_table a
join my_table b on a.D_id = b.D_id
  and a.D_category > b.D_category
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5885ff/2).

Answer (score 1):

or just make use of `row_number()`

```
select  *
from
(
    select  *, r = row_number() over (partition by D_id order by D_category)
    from    @A 
) a
where   a.r = 1
```